# Wordpress query post based on multiple date fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm looking for some expert help to solve a problem I'm having with a WordPress query. I have a post type with multiple date (repeater) fields. These fields are made with the ACF plugin. So one post has multiple dates that can be in the past and in the future. Now I want to query all these posts, ordered by date, but skip all dates that are in the past.

So i have multiple posts (like events) with multiple dates. For example:

Post A: date 1 may 2015, 20 may 2015, 23 may 2015, ect

Post B: date 3 may 2015, 16 may 2015, 20 may 2015, ect

Post C: date 2 may 2015, 15 may 2015, 26 may 2015, ect

And i want to show these post on first coming. So if today is 12 may i want to show Post C as first. And i want to hide date fields that are in the past.

This is the query i have right now (used acf documentations to get sub-field value as meta).

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$today = time();

// filter
function my_posts_where( $where ) {

    $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'data_%", "meta_key LIKE 'data_%", $where);

    return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');

// args
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'ndtrc',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page'=> 50,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'data_%_single_date',
            'compare'   => '<=',
            'value'     => $today,
        ),
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

?>

What's the right way to do this? I searched the forum but am not seeing the right way to accomplish this.

Comment: When you say "skip", do you mean "don't show posts that only have dates in the past", or "always show all posts, but only show future dates for those posts"?  Can you give an example of the data and what you want to see?

Comment: Thanx for your comment. So i have multiple posts (like events) with multiple dates. For example:

Post A: date 1 may 2015, 20 may 2015, 23 may 2015, ect

Comment: @Toasty Have you ever found a solution to this? I'm trying to archive the exact same thing!

Comment: Did anyone find a solution? I'm searching for this now.